# Allow PosixPrint Characters except , % \ / # ? : and except whitespace at the begining and end of string

Tags: regex, perl, pcre

So For this `Allow PosixPrint Characters except , % \ / # ? :` condition is working

with this regex pattern `m/^[^\P{PosixPrint}\/\#\%\?\:\,\\]+$/x`

But for this:

`white-space at the beginning and end but allow in the middle`

this pattern `m/^\b[^\P{PosixPrint}\/\#\%\?\:\,\\]+\b$/x` is kind of working (See the output).

It is not matching string if any characters appear at beginning and end except `[0-9a-zA-Z]`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $vars = [
    q#1#,
    q#1~`!l#,
    q#11#,
    q#111#,
    q#1 1#,
    q# 11#,
    q#11 #,
    q# 11 #,
    q# 1 1 #,
    q#1`~!@$^&*()-_=+|]}[{;'".><1#,
    q#1`~!@$^&*()-_=1#,
    q#1~`!@$^&*()-_=+|]}[{;'".><#,
    q#~`!@$^&*()-_=+|]}[{;'".><1#,
    q#~`!@$^&*()-_=+|]}[{;'".><#,
];

foreach my $var (@$vars){
    if ( $var =~ m/^\b[^\P{PosixPrint}\/\#\%\?\:\,\\]+\b$/x) {
        print "match:\t\t#$var#\n";
    }
    else{
        print "no match:\t#$var#\n";
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
    match:      #1#
    match:      #1~`!l#
    match:      #11#
    match:      #111#
    match:      #1 1#
    no match:   # 11#
    no match:   #11 #
    no match:   # 11 #
    no match:   # 1 1 #
    match:      #1`~!@$^&*()-_=+|]}[{;'".><1#
    match:      #1`~!@$^&*()-_=1#
    no match:   #1~`!@$^&*()-_=+|]}[{;'".><#
    no match:   #~`!@$^&*()-_=+|]}[{;'".><1#
    no match:   #~`!@$^&*()-_=+|]}[{;'".><#
```

**Expected OUTPUT:**

```
    match:      #1#
    match:      #1~`!l#
    match:      #11#
    match:      #111#
    match:      #1 1#
    no match:   # 11#
    no match:   #11 #
    no match:   # 11 #
    no match:   # 1 1 #
    match:      #1`~!@$^&*()-_=+|]}[{;'".><1#
    match:      #1`~!@$^&*()-_=1#
    match:      #1~`!@$^&*()-_=+|]}[{;'".><#
    match:      #~`!@$^&*()-_=+|]}[{;'".><1#
    match:      #~`!@$^&*()-_=+|]}[{;'".><#
```

**Information:**

```
Perl Version: v5.26.2
Platform: Ubuntu 18.10
```

Comment: **Javascript Regex:** `^(?!\s)[0-9A-Za-z\~\!\@\#\$\%\^\*\(\)\_\+\{\}\|\:\?\`\-\=\[\]\\\;\.\/]+(?<!\s)$` **Match:** `0-9a-zA-Z~!@#$%^*()_+{}|:?`-=[]\;./` **Not Match:** `, & < > ' " and Don't Allow space at the beginning and end.`

Comment: **Perl Regex:** `qr'^(?!\s)[^\P{PosixPrint}\,\<\>\'\"\&]+(?<!\s)$'` just like above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\b` is a word boundary, it is a boundary between a word character and a non word character.

Beginning and end of line are considered as non word character, so, `\b` at the end or at the beginning of a line will "match" only if there is a word character at first (last) char.

As far as I understand you want to reject lines that begin and/or end with space, use:

```
my $vars = [
    q#1#,
    q#1~`!l#,
    q#11#,
    q#111#,
    q#1 1#,
    q# 11#,
    q#11 #,
    q# 11 #,
    q# 1 1 #,
    q#1`~!@$^&*()-_=+|]}[{;'".><1#,
    q#1`~!@$^&*()-_=1#,
    q#1~`!@$^&*()-_=+|]}[{;'".><#,
    q#~`!@$^&*()-_=+|]}[{;'".><1#,
    q#~`!@$^&*()-_=+|]}[{;'".><#,
];

foreach my $var (@$vars){
    if ( $var =~ m/^(?!\h)[^\P{PosixPrint}\/\#\%\?\:\,\\]+(?<!\h)$/x) {
    #               ^^^^^^                                ^^^^^^^
        print "match:\t\t#$var#\n";
    }
    else{
        print "no match:\t#$var#\n";
    }
}
```

Where

- `(?!\h)` is a negative lookahead that make sure we haven't a horizontal space at first position
- `(?<!\h)` is a negative lookbehind that make sure we haven't a horizontal space at last position

**Output:**

```
match:      #1#
match:      #1~`!l#
match:      #11#
match:      #111#
match:      #1 1#
no match:   # 11#
no match:   #11 #
no match:   # 11 #
no match:   # 1 1 #
match:      #1`~!@$^&*()-_=+|]}[{;'".><1#
match:      #1`~!@$^&*()-_=1#
match:      #1~`!@$^&*()-_=+|]}[{;'".><#
match:      #~`!@$^&*()-_=+|]}[{;'".><1#
match:      #~`!@$^&*()-_=+|]}[{;'".><#
```

Comment: Problem 1: `\h` (horizontal whitespace) should be `\s` (whitespace)

Comment: Problem 2: `$` should be `\z` (or else it will allow a trailing Line Feed)

Comment: Problem 3: `+` should be `*` (or else it won't allow empty strings).

Answer (score 2):

The following is the pattern provided by the earlier answer with a few fixes:

```
/
   ^
   (?!\s)
   [^\P{PosixPrint}\\\/\#%?:,]*
   (?<!\s)
   \z
/x
```

The following in an optimization of the above:

```
/
    ^
    (?: [^\P{PosixPrint}\s\\\/\#%?:,]++
        (?: [^\P{PosixPrint}\S]++
            [^\P{PosixPrint}\s\\\/\#%?:,]++
        )*+
    )?+
    \z
/x
```

It's considered a better practice to state which characters are allowed (whitelist) rather than stating which ones aren't (blacklist). The latter approach is error-prone. The following are identical to the above solution, but use whitelisting instead of blacklisting:

```
/
    ^
    (?: [a-zA-Z0-9!"\$&'()*+\-.;<=>@[\]^_`{|}~]++
        (?: [ ]++
            [a-zA-Z0-9!"\$&'()*+\-.;<=>@[\]^_`{|}~]++
        )*+
    )?+
    \z
/x
```

or

```
/
    ^
    (?: (?&SAFE_CHAR)++
        (?: [ ]++
            (?&SAFE_CHAR)++
        )*+
    )?+
    \z

    (?(DEFINE)
       (?<SAFE_CHAR> [a-zA-Z0-9!"\$&'()*+\-.;<=>@[\]^_`{|}~] )
    )
/x
```